# Quick question about definition of connectedness and compactness.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, definition, compactness, connectedness

**Definition $1$**: Let $X$ be a metric space and $Y \subseteq X$. If every open cover of $Y$ has a finite subcover, we say that $Y$ is compact.

Question 1: Does the open cover consist of sets open relative to $X$, or to $Y$? (my guess would be $X$)

**Definition $2$**: Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. We say that $X$ is connected if we can't write $X$ as the disjoint union of $2$ non-empty, open sets. A subset $Y \subseteq X$ is connected if the metric subspace $(Y,d\vert_Y)$ is connected.

Question 2: Does this mean that we cannot write $Y$ as disjoint union of open subsets relative to $Y$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For the first question it doesn't matter. Given an open cover $U_i$ in terms of open sets of $X$, $Y \cap U_i$ gives an open cover of open sets of $Y$. Given an open cover $V_i$ of open sets of $Y$, each $V_i$ is some $Y \cap U_i$ where the $U_i$s are open sets of $X$ forming an open cover.
- For the second question it needs to be open sets of $Y$. The first example I can think of is just a topological space rather than a metric space, but the concepts should be the same for both. Consider the 'Real line with two zeroes', whose open sets are open sets of $\mathbb{R}$ but may contain one or both zeroes if the open set in $\mathbb{R}$ they come from contains $0$. Then the set $\{0, 0'\}$ is discrete and therefore disconnected, but any two open sets containing one of them intersect on the rest of the real line.

p.s. The answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/932088/two-definitions-of-connectedness-are-they-equivalent?rq=1) shows that this can't happen for metric spaces. Nevertheless, I think that it is always better to stick with definitions that are consistent for all topological spaces.

Answer (score 0):

1) relatively to $X$ or $Y$.

2) relatively to $Y$.