# If $A \cup B$ is disconnected then both $A$ and $B$ are open.

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ and $B$ be two disjoint non empty subsets of $\Bbb R^2$ such that $A \cup B$ is open in $\Bbb R^2$. Then prove or disprove *.

*If $A \cup B$ is disconnected then both $A$ and $B$ are open.

I saw, this question posted many times  on this site but I couldn't understand. I have confused with two solutions given below:

1st

"We know that open sets in $\Bbb R^2$ are either open balls or Union of open balls. So if $A \cup B$ is disconnected and $A \cap B = \varnothing \implies$ $A$ and $B$ are open sets."

2nd

"Take $A = \Bbb Q \setminus \{0\}$, $B = \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$ such that $A \cup B$ is disconnected but $A$ and $B$ are not open. "

Also I have know the result $A \cup B$ is disconnected if two set $A$ and $B$ such that $A \neq \varnothing$, $B \neq \varnothing$ with $\overline A \cap B = \varnothing$ , $ A \cap  \overline B = \varnothing$ . Here given that $A \cup B$ is disconnected then $\overline A \cap B = \varnothing$ , $ A \cap  \overline B = \varnothing$ . So $A \cap B = \varnothing$ which is given in the question. So * is correct. Please clear my doubt nicely. Thanks

Comment: For a counterexample you need to find an open but not connected subset of $\mathbb R^2$ that has at least one non-open subset. (Then you can all that non-open subset $A$ and the rest of your original set $B$).

Comment: @ Troposphere, I couldn't understand this counter example.

Comment: Your 2nd is a good counterexample. It doesn’t guarantee openness. Just because $A \cup B$ is open and a Union of open balls doesn’t mean either $A$ or $B$ or open.

Comment: Another is to just take two open balls, draw a line through both of them, everything on one side is A, everything on the other and on the line is B.

Comment: $A={0}$, $B=B_{\mathbb R^2}\setminus\{0\}\cup${any open set disjoint from $B_{\mathbb R^2}$}. ($B_{\mathbb R^2}$ is the open ball of radius 1)

Comment: @Eric, Please give an example in support of your comment.

Comment: @Eric, your comment " Another is to just take two open balls, draw a line through both of them, everything on one side is A, everything on the other and on the line is B" is nice. Please more elaborate it.

Comment: Might help: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/932088/27978

Comment: Let $C$ be any disconnected open subset of $\Bbb R^n$. Since $C$ is disconnected, it is not empty. Since $C$ is non-empty, and open, it has more than one point. So take $p\in C$ and let $A=\{p\}$ and let $B=C\setminus \{p\}.$

Answer (score 3):

Let $A=(0,1] \cup (4,5), B=(1,2) \cup (3,4]$.

$A,B$ are disjoint and non empty. $A \cup B$ is open and not connected.

However, neither $A$ nor $B$ are open.

Comment: Here $B$ is open. Union of open sets is open.

Comment: @Merabhai: But the claim was "... then both $A$ and $B$ are open". That means if even one of them is not-open, then the claim has failed.

Comment: Yes, this is a counterexample. I am not sure I understand your point?

Comment: Yes this is a counterexample. But it was useless: there was already one in the post.

Comment: @AnneBauval Sometimes a simpler counterexample helps people understand. Since I generally try to help people here, I would not deem it useless. Frankly I do not understand the point of your comment, especially since it written over two years ago.

Comment: I also generally try to help people. It would have been (more?) useful to let the OP say which point they do not understand in their own counterexample. And yes it is an old post, I saw it while reviewing the recent answer, and was interested by the whole question, comments, and answers.